# What tag can I use for a font-logo?

Tags: html, semantics

I have a logo which is just font and the name.

Now I was wondering what kind of tag would be best, semantic. 
Cause I think a simple `<a>` wouldn't let Google see it as a logo.
And considering it's a logo, I think it's quite important for a website.

Couldn't find in SO a similiar question.

Comment: For image: `<a href="/" rel="home"><img src="…" alt="Inc."></a>` ... For text: `<a href="/" rel="home">Inc.</a>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. It's not a image but literally a word with font-family.